# In swift : Whenever I'm sending JSON Request, Float 1.0 is converted to 1 but server thinks as Integer 1 and API fails, have any idea how to solve?

Tags: ios, json, swift

**I wanted to send 1.0 but not 1**

JSON data which is going to the server(python)
(don't want change in server side)

```
{ floatValue1 : 1, 
  name : "Jio", 
  floatValue2 : 1.12 
}
```

in Swift :

```
let value1 : Float = 1.0
let value2 : Float = 1.12
```

// just for demonstrating

```
HttpBody : [Strng : Any] = ["floatValue" : value1,
                            "name" : "Jio",
                            "floatValue" : value2]
```

Comment: looks ok to me, whats the actual issue?, 1 and 1.0 shouldn't really be any different to the server.

Comment: server is expecting Float, when finds Int API fails.

Comment: I wanted to send 1.0 but not 1

Comment: JSON only has a "number" type. It can't encode "float" or "int" as types. If your server is expecting non-standard JSON, then you'll likely need to create this string by hand. I don't believe there's a "numberEncodingStrategy" in the current JSONEncoder.